# asp.net razor web pages validation and using multiple forms

Tags: razor

i wanted to use two froms in my razor web pages(not mvc)
and my problem is working with more than one form
how do i say to my project that which form button is clicked and another problem is validation
because in web form project i was using validation group to separate validations but here
 i do not know how to deal with it both in client side validate and server side validation
here is my codes
:

```
@{
Page.Title = "";
Layout = "~/_layout.cshtml";

    Validation.Add("txt1", Validator.Required("can not leave empty"));
    Validation.Add("txt2", Validator.Required("can not leave empty"));


if (IsPost)
{

    if (!Validation.IsValid())
    {
    Validation.AddFormError("there are errors");
    }


}


}
    <style>
    .validation-summary-errors {
            border: 2px solid #990099;
            color: red;
        }

        .field-validation-error {
            color: Red;
        }

        .input-validation-error {
            color: #990099;
            background-color: #ff80ff;
            border-top: 2px solid #990099;
            border-left: 2px solid #990099;
        }
    </style>
    <div>
    <script src="~/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    </div>


 <p style="height:10px;"></p>

 <div>
<form name="f1" action="/" method="post">
<div>
    <input name="txt1" type="text" 
        class="@Validation.ClassFor("txt1")"
         />

    @Html.ValidationMessage("txt1")
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" name="s1" value="Send 1" />
</div>
</form>

</div>
<br />

<form name="f2" action="/" method="post">
<div>
    <input name="txt2" type="text" 
        class="@Validation.ClassFor("txt2")"
        />

    @Html.ValidationMessage("txt2")
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" name="s2" value="Send 2" />
</div>

 </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link for handling multiple form requests http://forums.asp.net/t/1678062.aspx/1

You can handle validation in each sub section. Hope that helps

Comment: thank royoston,thats help me out but the validation problam remains,
how do i handle validation for each form?

Answer (score 0):

You can determine which form was submitted by checking to see which submit button was clicked. Its name and value will be in the `Request.Form` collection. If the first form in your example code was submitted, `Request["s1"]` would have the value "Send 1". `Request["s2"].IsEmpty()` would be `true`.

The easiest way to get round the validation issue is to use the same name ("txt1") for both text boxes. Otherwise you will have to leave the Validation helpers and write your own conditional validation routines (client and server) based on which form is submitted.